# I want to throw custom Error with status code using Throw function in response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-404, status, throw

*If I use Throw new Error("User not found"), then it gives in response*

`{status:false,message:"User Not Found"}`

*But with status code 500, And I need Status 400 in Postman*

*custom Error* using throw function

but if we use `res.status(500).send({ status: false, message: "User not found" })`

then it gives status code 400, And I need Status 400 in Postman . So, I need same status code in postman only.This is the problem. Tyler2P and Abin Bala , I followed your code but I am unable to get desired status code in postman status.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Throwing an error in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086247/throwing-an-error-in-node-js)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom error class as below and throw it with appropriate message and httpCode. You can also add more properties. Then you can catch the custom error object using the catch block and get the required values.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  name;
  httpCode;
  message;
  
  
  constructor(name,httpCode, message){
    super(message);
    this.name = name;
    this.httpCode = httpCode;
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

`errorThrowingFunction.js`:

```
//import the custom error class in the module that you //are   going to use it.
errorThrowingFunction = () => {
  const authToken = myCache.get("token");
      
  if (!authToken) {
    throw new CustomError('Error',401,'token missing');
  } else {
    return authToken;
  }
}
```

`index.js`:

```
handler = () => {
  try {
    errorThrowingFunction();
  } catch(error){
    const response = {
      statusCode: error.httpCode,
      body: JSON.Stringify(error.message),
      isBase64Encoded: false,
      //add other headers
    }
    return response;
    //if you are using this in rest service, the use below line
    //return res.status(error.httpCode)send(response);
  }
}
```