# How to get (return) a value out of a callback

Tags: javascript, electron

Good evening! How can I return a value from a callback function in my case? Thanks!

```
ipcMain.handle("get-menu-data", () => {
  foo((response) => {
    menuData = response;
    console.log(menuData); // [ { id: 2, title: 'Google' }, { id: 6, title: 'Bing' } ]
  });
  console.log(menuData); // menuData is not defined
  return menuData; //I need to return this variable from ipcMain.handle function to preload.js.
});

function foo(callback) {
  db.all("SELECT * FROM projects", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return callback(res);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem**

You can't `return` from an asynchronous callback. But there's another issue, if an error happens, the caller of `foo` will wait indefinitely for the callback to be called.

```
function foo(callback) {
  db.all("SELECT * FROM projects", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // ❌ callback is never called
    } else {
      return callback(res); // ❌ return does nothing here
    }
  });
}
```

Do you notice how `db.all` passes `(err, res)` to the callback? This is a node-style [error-first callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33086864/633183).

**option 1**

Write `foo` to accept a node-style error-first callback -

```js
function foo(callback) {
  db.all("SELECT * FROM projects", (err, res) => {
    if (err)
      callback(err) // ✅ callback with error
    else
      callback(null, res) // ✅ callback with null error and response
  })
```

Which is exactly the same as writing this simplified form -

```js
function foo(callback) {
  db.all("SELECT * FROM projects", callback)
}
```

[ipcMain.handle](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) accepts an asynchronous promise-based handler. We can wrap `foo` in a promise like so -

```js
ipcMain.handle("get-menu-data", () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    foo((err, res) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(res)
    })
  })
})
```

**option 2**

I think it would be better to convert `foo` to a promise-based function -

```js
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.all("SELECT * FROM projects", (err, res) => {
      if (err) reject(err) // ✅ errors are rejected
      else resolve(res) // ✅ response is resolved
    })
  })
}
```

Now write asynchronous handler -

```js
ipcMain.handle("get-menu-data", async () => {
  const menuData = await foo()
  return menuData
})
```

However, since `foo` already returns a Promise, you can rewrite this more easily -

```js
ipcMain.handle("get-menu-data", () => {
  return foo()
})
```

Even easier -

```js
ipcMain.handle("get-menu-data", foo)
```

**option 3**

Node has a built-in function called [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) that converts a callback-based function to a promised-based one. Instead of creating a `foo` wrapper function, we can promisify `db.all` directly -

```js
import { promisify } from "node:util"

const query = promisify(db.all)

ipcMain.handle("get-menu-data", () => {
  return query("SELECT * FROM projects")
})
```